# Open controller after notification tap on watchkit

Tags: ios, objective-c, xamarin, push-notification, apple-watch

I'm trying to have two different states for my apple watch app.

Either the user starts the app from the home screen, in which case the controller should be the initial controller. That's working fine.

Either the user open the apps from a notification, in which case I'd like another controller to be loaded.

I've tried using the `reloadrootcontrollers`, push/segues, and really using whatever I could find in the documentation, and the results I had were the following

- The app would show an error : `*********** ERROR -[SPRemoteInterface _interfaceControllerClientIDForControllerID:] clientIdentifier for interfaceControllerID:(null) not found`
- The controller would be loaded as a "next page" after my initial controller. I don't want that.
- My other controller would simply not be there, and the app would start as if I started it from the home screen.

This must be simple but I can't get my head around it with the watch kit.

I'm using Xamarin but any objective-C / swift answer will suffice.

**What should I do to open a controller if the user tapped on a notification?**

Note : My notifications have no buttons except the built-in "dismiss".

Comment: What is crash stack trace? -`reloadRootControllersWithNames:contexts:` should be good enough. Used same approach to choose correct controller when `-applicationDidFinishLaunching` get called and it didn't crash.

Comment: -applicationDidFinishLaunching ? There is no appDelegate in the watchkit now, is there?!
i'll show you the error in a minute, the time I need to go back in that state

Comment: I edited to show the error I get. There is actually no crash I don't know why I phrased it like that.

Comment: I call `-reloadRootControllers` in the `-DidreceiveRemoteNotification` in my NotificationController, maybe that is the problem?

Comment: `WKExtensionDelegate` has `-applicationDidFinishLaunching` as well as `-handleActionWithIdentifier:forRemoteNotification:` which you can try to use to call `-reloadRootControllersWithNames:contexts:` from it.